# How to recover color palette in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3

Something strange happened to me recently. I was testing the color schemes of Sublime Text 3 by selecting them from the menu Sublime Text  > Preferences > Color Scheme. I did not find any that I liked more than my current one, but then I realized that the one I was using was not among the color schemes listed. Unfortunately I do not remember the name of the color scheme I was using.

By searching for popular color schemes online, I found one that is close: "Afterglow-twilight". However, the scheme I was using had much higher contrast, i.e. darker background and more vivid code highlight colors.

Is there a way in Sublime Text 3 to recover the color scheme I was using?

Comment: your color scheme is defined as `"color_scheme"` in `Preferences.sublime-settings - User`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color scheme that you're using is set as the `color_scheme` setting in your user preferences and the menu item `Preferences > Color Scheme` (which is under `Sublime Text` if you're on MacOS) allows you to more easily set that preference by showing you a list of all <s>all</s> most available color schemes along with letting you preview what they look like.

The short answer to your question is `No`, but the longer answer to your question is `Yes`.

The `No` is because unless you have your `Preferences.sublime-settings` file backed up somewhere (say if you use Dropbox to sync it) or under version control of some sort, then the value of the setting is gone now and the only way to get it back is to figure out what color scheme you were using so that you can reset it.

The `Yes` is because Sublime will only allow you to use color schemes that you have installed locally, and using the menu item outlined above allows you to pick between those you have installed (changing the setting as appropriate) but it doesn't remove any installed color schemes.

That means that unless you uninstalled a package in between when you were playing and noticed that your color scheme is no longer listed, that color scheme is still present even if the list isn't displaying it (and if you did uninstall a package, re-installing the package will bring it back). So all you need to do is figure out what it was.

There's a <s>strikethrough</s> in the first paragraph because Sublime hides some color schemes from you, so if you were using one of those it won't appear in the list and you need other means to find it.

The first thing to try is to add the following setting to your user settings (if it's not already there) to tell Sublime that legacy color schemes should also be listed:

```
"show_legacy_color_schemes": true,
```

Around the time the menu item for changing color schemes was added to the interface, some of the color schemes that used to ship with Sublime were relegated to Legacy status because they were wildly out of date and either not popular enough to warrant work to update them or impossible to fix without making visual changes.

Those color schemes are still present, but they're masked from the list of displayed color schemes unless you turn that setting on. So, in the case that you happened to be using one of those previously, this setting should let you find it again. Syntaxes that fall into this category will say `Color Scheme - Legacy` under them in the list.

If that doesn't turn up the color scheme that you were using, there is one last avenue of exploration. Sublime supports the idea of a hidden color scheme, which is generally something used by packages to give color schemes to things without more generally exposing them. Possibly there is a Theme out there for Sublime that distributes it's color schemes this way as well.

If you open the Sublime console with `View > Show Console`, you can enter the following lines one at a time into the input at the bottom of the window:

```py
sublime.find_resources("*.hidden-tmTheme")
sublime.find_resources("*.hidden-color-scheme")
```

This will get Sublime to show you a list of all of the hidden color schemes (there are two different formats). Assuming either list is not empty, the items in the list represent hidden color schemes that the command mentioned above doesn't display.

If so, you can open your user preferences and manually set the `color_scheme` setting to each of the items in turn to see if one of them is the one you're looking for.

Comment: My color scheme was indeed a legacy one, Twilight to be precise. Thank you very much! The prospect of not seeing Sublime Text as I was used to ever again was surprisingly troubling for me :).